# Best practices while designing databases in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, jakarta-ee, database-design

I am developing an Enterprise application in Java EE and I think it will have a huge amount of stored data. It is similar to a University management application in which all colleges students are registered and have their profile.

I am using a MySQL database. I tried to explore on the internet and I found some tips on this [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/).

What are the best practices to develop huge databases so that they do not decrease its performance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Essentially: model your database correctly, implement it correctly and program the clients for it correctly. But what "correctly" means is the subject of whole books and is far beyond the scope of a humble SO post...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all your database is not huge but medium -> small size. Huge database is when you need to deal with terabytes of data and million operations per second. Considering your case, MySQL (MyISAM) is enough and rather than optimization you should focus on correct database design (optimization is the next step).

Let me share some tips with you:

- scale your hardware (not so important for your case)
- identify relations (normalize) and correct datatypes (i.e. use tiny int instead of big int if you can)
- try to avoid NULL if possible
- user varchar instead of text/blob if possible
- index your tables (remember indexes slow update/delete/insert operations)
- design your queries in a correct way (use indexes)
- always use transactions

Once you design and develop your database and the performance is not sufficient - think about optimization:
- check explain plans and tune sqls
- check hardware utilization and tune either system or mysql parameters (i.e. query cache).

Please check also this link:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html